# Fill items List in List from another List

Tags: c#, linq, list, windows-phone-8, reference

Hey I have two List in `MainViewModel`

```
public List<CategoryItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
public List<QuestionItem> QuestionList { get; set; }

CategoryList = new List<CategoryItem>(); 
QuestionList = new List<QuestionItem>();
```

`QuestionItem` also have another MyObject `QuestionDetails`

In `CategoryItem` I have Id's List off all questions in one category. 
In `QuestionList` I have 2000 questions

`CategoryItem` have `list<QuestionItem> QuestionItemsList`

and now I want to fill `QuestionItemsList` with all questions where `Question.ID` exist in `CategoryItem.IdList`

after that I want to clear `QuestionList`, but when I did it I also clear `QuestionItemsList`, because the are connected by reference

Comment: My easy solution: add new instance of `QuestionItem` every time when you add it to list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead :

```
QuestionItemsList.Add(QuestionList[0])
```

Try:

```
QuestionItemsList.Add(new QuestionItem { X = QuestionList[0].X, (...) } )
```

You will loose reference *connection*. You can also use MemberwiseClone method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
QuestionItemsList.Add((QuestionItem)QuestionList[0].MemberwiseClone() )
```